# Putting unsigned app onto a phone

Tags: android, apk

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get your app to a phone to test (not on the market just from computer to phone)? I tried gmail and google docs but gmail gave me a parsing error and google docs put it in some weird format so I can't even download it. I have a blog but I have no idea how or even if I can attach a file to that for download. Any suggestions?

I do have a usb cord for my phone but I wanted to email a link or the file to a friend so they can test it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your phone, go to applications, and enable the "install unsigned applications" or something like that, then simply load the app file that you built onto the SD card in some way.  Then install it with an installer application such as AppInstaller, or Astro file management.  Both of these apps are free, and are how we used to do device testing when working on our android game at my previous company

Comment: So just move it to my sd card with my usb cord? I'll try that and see how it works

Comment: NVM I used dropbox to download it. I wanted to do a link so I can have my friend test it too.